# Phaser.js - текст, привязанный к спрайту, двигается не синхронно с ним

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Пример в [песочнице](https://phaser.io/sandbox/edit/NCSfUkCW) Движение спрайта по левой кнопке мыши.

Унаследуем спрайт:

```
import 'phaser';

/**
 * Represents a unit
 */
class Ship extends Phaser.Sprite{
    constructor(game, x, y, color, radius, frame) {
        let bmd, style;

        //Bitmap data
        bmd = game.make.bitmapData(radius*2, radius*2);
        bmd.circle(radius, radius, radius, color);
        super(game, x, y, bmd, frame);

        //add the sprite to the stage
        game.add.existing(this);

        //text data
        style = { font: "9px Arial", fill: "#fff", wordWrap: true, wordWrapWidth: this.width, align: "center" };
        this.text = game.add.text(0, 0, "B", style);
        this.text.anchor.set(0.5, 0.3);

        this.updateTextPos ();
    }

    /**
     * Update text coords
     */
    updateTextPos ()  {
        this.text.x = Math.floor(this.x + this.width/2);
        this.text.y = Math.floor(this.y + this.height/2);
    }
}
export default Ship;
```

Максимально стандартный стартер из любого туториала по [Phaser.js](https://phaser.io/)

```
import 'p2';
import 'pixi';
import 'phaser';
import Ship from './ships/ship';

let game = new Phaser.Game(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, Phaser.WEBGL, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

function preload() {
    game.load.image('background', '/assets/images/background.jpg');
}


let player,
    cursors;

function create() {
    game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 2884, 2064, 'background');
    game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 2884, 2064);

    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);

    player = new Ship(game, game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY,  'rgba(255,0,0,0.8)', 8);

    game.physics.enable(player, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    game.camera.follow(player);
}

function update() {

    //  only move when you click
    if (game.input.mousePointer.isDown)
    {
        //  400 is the speed it will move towards the mouse
        game.physics.arcade.moveToPointer(player, 200);

        //  if it's overlapping the mouse, don't move any more
        if (Phaser.Rectangle.contains(player.body, game.input.x, game.input.y))
        {
            player.body.velocity.setTo(0, 0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        player.body.velocity.setTo(0, 0);
    }

    //redraw text
    player.updateTextPos();

}
```

Кружок с надписью B нормально передвигается за курсором, здесь вопросов нет. 
Но надпись на кружке на скорости перерисовывается с запозданием, смещаясь к краю. 
В момент остановки она возвращается на середину, как и положено. 
В чем может быть причина? Может, есть способы по-другому добавить текстовую информацию к спрайту?

Без движения:

[image: Без движения:]

В движении:

[image: В движении]

Делал по [туториалу](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/text/center-text-on-sprite)
Техника та - же. На каждую отрисовку отцентровываем текст на спрайте. Код проходит через babel. Может ли проблема быть следствием оверхеда из-за генерируемого ES5-кода?